# How to update select with jquery in rails?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, html-select

I have the following script in my _form2.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
        $('#toright').click(function () {
            var sel = document.getElementById("left");
            var len = sel.options.length;
            var w_id = this.getAttribute('w_id');
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                {
                if(sel.options[i].selected) 
                    {
                    $.ajax("/r_holidays/destroy", {holiday_id: sel.options[i].value, group_id: w_id}).done(function(data){/*do something here*/});
                    ##########HERE SHOULD BE AN UPDATE-METHOD########
                    }
                }
        })
      });

$(function () {
        $('#toleft').click(function () {
            var sel = document.getElementById("right");
            var len = sel.options.length;
            var w_id = this.getAttribute('w_id');
            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) 
                {
                if(sel.options[i].selected) 
                    {

                    $.ajax("/r_holidays/create", {holiday_id: sel.options[i].value, group_id: w_id}).done(function(data){/*do something here*/});
                    ##########HERE SHOULD BE AN UPDATE-METHOD########
                    }
                } 
        })
      });
</script>
```

This only creates this small exchange-table:
[image]

The ID of the green select is "left", the right-ones is "right".
What I want is that it updates the left table, when the AJAX-Method is excuted.

I've allready googled a lot, but I can't find the method, I need.
Can anyone help me out?

EDIT [@Anoop Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2281280/anoop-joshi):

Well, I thaught it could rerender the content serverside, and then reload it client side.
This is my code, which needs just to be reloaded:

```
<%= form_tag({}, {}) do %>
    <% holidays_array = @group.holidays.all.map { |holiday| [holiday.name, holiday.id] } %>
    <%= select(:holiday_id, :name, options_for_select(holidays_array),{}, {:multiple => true, :style => "width: 300px; background-color: #9FE", :width => "300", :size => 20, :id=>"right" }  ) %>
<% end %>
```

EDIT:

I don't want to add some options to my select. I just need to update the whole select, or if needed the  in the file.

Comment: how is your ajax response look like?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: What happens is that when I click on << it creates RHolidays (which stand for many to many relations) with the ID of "eine gruppe" and the IDs of the selected holidays.
The >> deletes the RHolidays (which stand for many to many relations) with the ID of "eine gruppe" and the IDs of the selected holidays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, your success data look likes this,

```
data = [{
    "id": 123,
    "value": "abc"
}, {
    "id": 1234,
    "value": "abcas"
}, {
    "id": 1232,
    "value": "abcs"
}];
```

Then your code will be,

```
$.ajax("/r_holidays/destroy", {
    holiday_id: sel.options[i].value,
    group_id: w_id
}).done(function (data) {

    $(data).each(function () {
        $("#left").append($("<option/>", {
            value: this.id,
            html: this.value
        }));
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you,
But isn't there an option, to reload a <div id="left"></div>?
That would be much more easy.

Comment: I've edited the Original question, to show, which code needs to be rerendered.